# Python large dimension Sparse Array

Tags: python

Can anyone recommend any python packages for using Sparse Arrays with more than 2 dimensions.
I'm looking for something similar to a numpy.array with dimension n1xn2xn3xn4xn5. 
The array is basically a 3 dimensional grid where each grid entry contains a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy works fine. Simply do:

`numpy.zeros((100, 100, 100, 100, 100))` - you'll get a 5D array with all zeros.